# How to stop uiactivityindicator after waiting for in-app purchase store to load

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, uiactivityindicatorview

I thought one of these would do it, none of them are getting called -_-

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"flag paymentQueue");
```

//        spinner.hidden=YES; //where does this go?

```
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            //    [self stillPurchasing]; // this creates an alertView and shows
                NSLog(@"flag SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing");

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"flag SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"flag SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");

                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"flag SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");

                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
           //     spinner.hidden=YES;
                break;
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide spinner in following method-

```
    - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
      [target hideSpinner];
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be good. You should hide your spinner in the 3 cases : 
- SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased 
- SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed 
- SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored

Have you checked your delegates ? 
your class should implement the delegate method of :
-> SKPaymentTransactionObserver

Mine is declared like that : 
    @interface InAppPurchaseStoreManager : NSObject

Comment: SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased and SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed are for if the user buys product or presses cancel right? I want to hide the uiiactivityindicator when apple's in app purchase alert view first comes up, right now my spinner is visible behind the alert view. -thanks for the help!!

Comment: You were right about the delegate Diwann, thanks!! Also i was loading the store earlier, thinking this would speed things up. Loading when needed and then when the products are received seems to be a good place to stop the spinner.